# oracle database AUDIT doesn't show SQL text and bind values

Tags: oracle, audit

Based on this [tutorial](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php) I have configured auditing on a database with these options:

```
AUDIT ALL BY db BY ACCESS;
AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY db BY ACCESS;
AUDIT EXECUTE PROCEDURE BY db BY ACCESS;
```

I prepare query from java and run a `SELECT` query. `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` table shows my `SELECT` query but `SQL_TEXT` and `SQL_BIND` fields are empty. How can I see them? Should I enable any other option? I'm using Oracle 11.2 Express Edition. Is this because It is express edition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The column `SQLTEXT` and `SQLBIND` are populated only when `AUDIT_TRAIL` option is set to `db, extended`. Here is an example:

```
SQL> alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;

System altered
```

Restart the instance.

```
SQL> audit select on your_table;

Audit succeeded

SQL> select sqltext from sys.aud$ where obj$name = 'YOUR_TABLE';

SQLTEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
null

SQL> select count(*) from your_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         3

SQL> select sqltext from sys.aud$ where obj$name = 'YOUR_TABLE';

SQLTEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select count(*) from your_table


SQL>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be "...when AUDIT_TRAIL option is set to db" instead of "... dba" ?

Comment: if using Toad the result set is a little quirky, you wont see the results if you run F9- you see "(HUGECLOB)". run F5 and switch to the grid pane and you will not see the comments of the CLOB. i.e. your statement